# Preserving subtypes when creating new instances in the parent class

Tags: scala

I have the following (simplified) class that wraps a `Map`:

```
class Store(val values: Map[String, String]) {
  def set(name: String, value: String): Store = new Store(values + (name -> value))
  def remove(name: String): Store = new Store(values - name)
}
```

I'd like to have other classes extend it to override, say, the `toString` method:

```
class PrintableStore(values: Map[String, String]) extends Store(values) {
  override def toString: String = values.toString
}
```

The problem, obvious in hindsight, is that `set` and `remove` return instances of `Store`: the value returned by these methods are not of the correct type, and I'm loosing my enhanced `toString` method.

The only solution I could find was to define `Store` as a trait with a self type as follows:

```
trait Store[+Self] {
  this: Self =>

  def values: Map[String, String]
  def copy(values: Map[String, String]): Self

  def set(name: String, value: String): Self = copy(values + (name -> value))
  def remove(name: String): Self = copy(values - name)

}

class PrintableStore(val values: Map[String, String]) extends Store[PrintableStore] {
  override def toString: String = values.toString
  override def copy(values: Map[String, String]): PrintableStore = new PrintableStore(values)
}
```

This works fine, but requires what I feel is a surprising amount of boilerplate for Scala code:

- all subclasses will have an implementation of `copy` that is essentially the same.
- all subclasses will always pass themselves as the parameter type to `Store`.

Is there a better solution to this issue, or am I spoiled and my boilerplate threshold too low?
I must admit that while I feel that I understand self types, I'm not entirely comfortable using them yet and the previous code might very well be entirely incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something similar to what the collections library does:

```
trait StoreLike[T <: StoreLike[T]] {
  val values: Map[String, String]
  def set(name: String, value: String): T = build(values + (name -> value))
  def remove(name: String): T = build(values - name)
  def build(values: Map[String, String]): T
}

class Store(val values: Map[String, String]) extends StoreLike[Store] {
  def build(values: Map[String, String]): Store = new Store(values)
}

class PrintableStore(val values: Map[String, String]) extends StoreLike[PrintableStore] {
  override def toString: String = values.toString()
  def build(values: Map[String, String]): PrintableStore = new PrintableStore(values)
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you don't coerce T to a StoreLike in the definition of StoreLike?

Comment: Oversight, let me add it.

Comment: I like the idea, especially since it means `Store` is a concrete implementation. On the other hand, I believe this will not compile, `StoreLike` requires a type parameter, even used as a type parameter to itself (`trait StoreLike[T <: StoreLike[T]]`). As a matter of curiosity, would there be any point in making `StoreLike` covariant on `T`?

Comment: Yes I've updated it. Now it's f bounded polymorphic.

Comment: Sorry, one last updated required to make this the canonical answer: `StoreLike` needs to have `T` as a self type in order to be able to reference `this` as an instance of `T` - say, if you want to optimise `set` and have it return the current instance if the underlying map already contains the specified key / value pair.